# EasyHook .NET 4.0.x dllNotFound in EasyHook EasyHook32.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, easyhook

I'm using EasyHook in my c# project and have included easyhook.dll as a reference for the project. I tried to add easyhook32.dll and easyhook64.dll, however Visual Studio says

`A reference to [path/to/easyhook32.dll] could not be added. Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component`

When I attempt to use EasyHook.dll in my program EasyHook throws a `System.DllNotFoundException` because of not being able to find `EasyHook32.dll`.

I have tried putting it in the bin and debug folders however, neither seem to fix the issue. I have also tried running both VS and a compiled version of the application as administrator, to no avail.

Any ideas?

I'm using .NET 4.0.x on Visual Studio 2013 and the latest release of EasyHook

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the references and using the Nuget package. That's how I have installed it, and it is working great. It does currently put

- EasyHook.dll
- EasyHook.xml
- EasyHook32.dll
- EasyHook32Svc.exe
- EasyHook64.dll
- EasyHook64Svc.exe
- EasyLoad32.dll
- EasyLoad64.dll

In the debug folder.

Alternatively, it might be a dependency of EasyHook32.dll that it isn't able to load, so try putting EasyLoad32.dll in the folder as well.

Your VS reference should be to the EasyHook.dll, and the other dlls should be added as content to be copied to the bin/Debug|Release dir.